# ASP.NET: How do you debug dynamically loaded user controls using LoadControl(string path);

Tags: asp.net, debugging

ASP.NET: How do you debug dynamically loaded user controls using LoadControl(string path);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything is part of the same solution and built in debug -  I believe you should be able to just place a breakpoint in your user control and it will get hit.

Alternatively, in your project that contains the user control you could use Ctrl-Alt-P to attach the project to the IIS process (or WebDev.WebServer process if you're using Visual Studios built in web server aka Cassini).  This way you could debug that project on it's own.

Comment: You are correct. Though for some reason it didnt work for me before asking the question. Maybe i was doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Posted an alternative method that could work for you as well.